# CodeIgniter Setting cookies, cookies not setting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've searched here and on google before asking this cause I see its a popular question, but the answers I have found I have tried, and still I am failing.

This is my attempt to set the cookies (note the helper is autoloaded)

```
$longlife = 60*60*24*60; //60 days
$shortlife = 60*60*24*10; //10 days
$this->input->set_cookie('AutoRemember', $user.'::'.$hashbrown, $shortlife, '.example.com', '/');
$this->input->set_cookie('LongRemember', $user.'::'.$hashbrown, $longlife, '.example.com', '/');
```

when I attempt to do a var_dump on '$this->input->cookie()` i get bool false as an output, meaning no cookies found. This is the first time i've tried using cookies with CI so the issue is beyond me at the moment.

also note I changed the real domain in the example above to example.com as I don't want the domain to show up in searches right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__ ***Edited Oct 3, 2013 For Claritiy*** __

Alright, I figure out what my problem was, and I am sure this will help new comers down the road as well. So, when your initially setting up your `application/config/config.php`

You will find a line:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
```

This setting while given the impression is optional, is as it turns out more of a requirement. There appears to be a bug, of which is not always reproducible, so its hard to track what and why. Bottom line is though, if this config item is not set. On a good handful of occasions while the cookie is setting/getting it will break silently under the hood. Leaving you with the impression that it is working when it isn't.

Imagine how frustrating that can be. Anyway, my fix for the original problem was to set the prefix line mentioned above. Anything will do, coders choice.

Anyway, note worthy mention for those intent on setting it. When you set a cookie you do it normally as per the document/guide.

```
$this-input->set_cookie('myCookie');
```

However, what I noticed the document doesn't specify (or didn't last I checked) was that the prefix you set

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "cmh_";//example
```

will not get you the cookie value when you call it like one would think they should which the doc says to do ie:

```
$this->input->cookie('myCookie');
```

calling the value out like this will most likely result in seeing nothing on the screen. If you did a `var_dump()` for example. you would get `bool(false)`. In other words meaning it can't find the cookie your referencing. Which is true. It can't it doesn't exist, remember you set a prefix. To get your cookie at that point you will need to do something like

```
$this->input->cookie('cmh_myCookie');
```

which will print out the actual value of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can not set cookies for domain 'example.com' from within a domain (HTTP_HOST) with a different name like 'yoursite.com'. it is security issue, browsers will ignore it. check with mozilla firebug 'NET' tab the response headers, if the cookie exists, and not set , then i am right.

secondly, after you set cookie, it will be available on the server (php) , only in next request, since current $_COOKIE still not updated. if CI implemented this differently, this is  wrong implementation of the concept.

Comment: "also note I changed the real domain in the above example...", and the page goes from one to another after the cookie should have been set, so I think I'm covered there.

Comment: missed this line with "also note..." , sorry.
what about firebug??? do you see the cookies header in response or not ? and what you mean from one page to another ?

Comment: its ok, wasn't trying to be offensive either, after re-reading what I wrote initially, could have worded that better. Anyway however I found out what my issue was to one extent, still having a bit of trouble but I think at this point its logic based and not cookie specific. The problem as it was turned out that in the config you have settings for prefixing a cookie with something, if its left blank the cookies break in the background and never get set, if you have something set then your looking for that setting + what you called the cookie in the script, I wasn't looking for a prefix + name

Comment: thanks for clarifying. i remember one of my team members got crazy because of some CI cookie issue, may be this post will help others to avoid it in the future )

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CodeIgniter's Session Class instead.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I am, but tell me, how do I extend the session for 10+ days after the user has closed the browser initially or even restarted there computer? If thats possible with sessions I am all ears :-)

Comment: In the config.php file you can specify expiration. $config['sess_expiration'] = (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2); In my case, I set the expiration for 2 weeks.

Answer (score -1):

From the docs:

```
This function is identical to the post function, only it fetches cookie data:
$this->input->cookie('some_data', TRUE);
```

Well, as this suggests, you will need to add the name of the cookie to get it. Try outputting `$this->input->cookie('AutoRemember')`

Comment: tried that at first, tried it again just now for sanity sake, stil bool(false)

Comment: could see by document.cookie method if the cookies are being set (JS)?

Comment: walked away for the night to come back with a fresh head, and yea.. nothing I do is setting cookie. If I use PHP's native command for setting cookies I run into a header issue as I am also using sessions for other needs.